# DATABASE autocreation bash script: What's wrong?

Tags: mysql, bash

My bash script won't crate the Database. What am I doing wrong here?
Please have a look:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
set -x

function deebee() {

EXPECTED_ARGS=2
E_BADARGS=65
MYSQL=`which mysql`

Q1="CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $1;"
Q2="GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO $2@localhost IDENTIFIED BY '$3';"
Q3="GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON $1.* TO $2@localhost;"
Q4="FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
SQL="${Q1}${Q2}${Q3}${Q4}"

if [ $# -ne $EXPECTED_ARGS ]
then
  echo "Usage: $0 dbname dbuser dbpass"
  exit $E_BADARGS
fi

$MYSQL -uroot -p -e "$SQL"

}

deebee $1 $2 $3
```

I'm calling the script as I've put it in a function, but it just spits out the expected arguments telling me the syntax, i.e that I should type in the bashscrip name, dbname, dbuser dbpass, but obviously there' something wrong with the script of my login permissions or user so that I can't automate this... What's going on, I'd love to know!
Thanks!

Comment: Why is `EXPECTED_ARGS` 2 if you want 3 arguments?

Comment: What's supposed to happen if the arguments passed contain malicious input?

Comment: Sorry I forgot that I wanted to change the $2 to the same value as $1 so that the database and database user have the same name, so the password which was $3 would become $2. I'm also not sure about the second question, what malicious input could be added, I mean its just for username and password. But yes, poignant reminder, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What I would do :

creating a `mysql` config file with credentials (easier to automate now) :

```
cat ~/.my.cnf 
[client]
host     = localhost
user     = root
password = xxx
```

And the script :

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x

deebee() {
    EXPECTED_ARGS=3
    E_BADARGS=65
    MYSQL=$(type -p mysql)


    if (($# != $EXPECTED_ARGS))
    then
      echo "Usage: $0 dbname dbuser dbpass"
      exit $E_BADARGS
    fi

    $MYSQL <<EOF
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS '$1';
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO '$2'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$3';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON '$1'.* TO '$2'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
EOF

}

# TODO tests on input args

deebee "$1" "$2" "$3"
```

And like [Denis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/417194/denis) said in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21080117/database-autocreation-bash-script-whats-wrong/21081012#comment31706238_21080117), take care of what users can put as arguments to prevent sql injection.

You should add some tests on input args.